# Received notification of reply in chat even though I never participated in chat room

Tags: bug, chat, notifications, global-inbox

I received a reply notification in my inbox (by clicking on top left corner "StackExchange" widget and clicking "Inbox" bullet) even though I have never participated in chat.

The URL of the chat post they were replying to:

> https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/36028#36028

Here are the URLs of the replies in question:

> https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/36377#36377
> https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/36208#36208

Looks like it was to another user named [Andrew](https://stackoverflow.com/users/305627/andrew).

Comment: Well, this certainly reminds me we should add years to the transcript pages -- those links are from 2010 :) How come you're reporting this only now? And define "participate" -- had you ever *been* to the chat room?

Comment: This must come from *somewhere*.. sure you didn't write this? Year and half is long time.

Comment: Are you sure you hadn't joined the room at any point before that? Just visiting a room renders you pingable for some duration of time.

Comment: Wow - are they really from 2010? I only clicked on the "StackExchange" widget for the first time yesterday, so I guess the notification has been sitting in there since 2010. I have been reading other bug questions similar to mine and it looks like this is by design. From memory, I have only ever been to the chat room once, a long time ago, which is probably why I got the notification. It doesn't help that my username is an incredibly common one. I have to say, though, this feature does not follow the principal of least astonishment.